# dj and god memory leak in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

We have delayed_job to handle background processing in our app. God monitors the more-memory-consuming DJ workers now and then and cut them off.

This setup has been working perfectly for months with daily deploys. Now today, suddenly all the workers once they are started consumes 400+ MB memory each. There were no deploys in the last few days.

What could have gone wrong? please help. The app is running on Ruby 1.9.2 with Rails 3.0.5.

Answer (score 2):

Current versions of ruby 1.9.2 ship with a version of psych (the new YAML parser) that leaks memory. If `YAML::ENGINE.yamler` is 'psych' and `Psych::VERSION` is 1.0.0 then you are using an affected version.

There are several ways out. You can (in no particular order)

1. Not use psych. This can be a little tricky since bundler tries to load psych. You need to reset `YAML::ENGINE.yamler` to 'syck' after bundler has changed it but before delayed job loads (because delayed job has some YAML backend specific code and you need it to load the right one.
2. Use ruby 1.9.3. It ships with a newer version of psych.
3. Install a newer version of psych as a gem. While this sounds ideal it is a little bit fiddly as you want this gem around before bundler loads (so that when bundler loads it loads the new version of psych) but of course when bundler loads you only see gems installs in the system. I ended up installing psych both as a "normal" gem and specifying it in the gemfile. There are a few other hoops you may need to jump through which all revolve around making sure no one loads the bad version of psych. I wrote a little bit more about my adventures with this on my [blog](http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/1/26/memory-leak-in-yaml-on-ruby-1-9-2)

Comment: Im wondering, how can this suddenly happen to the dj workers?

Comment: the workers, once started quickly goes from 70MB to 500MB before doing any work.. we didn't update any version of ruby/rails

Comment: Did you upgrade to dj 3.0 recently? There are a bunch of things that can influence what YAML backend is picked. It's easy to see what backend is being used - see my answer

Comment: No. its been freezed to delayed_job (2.1.4) for a long time - may be 6 months or so..

Answer (score 1):

Transparent PNGs rendered in a PDF using Prawn caused this huge memory consumption. The workers were doing PDF generation.